# Principal values of complex functions

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I find the principal value of the following:

$\log(1-\sqrt{2i})$

And hence of

$(1-\sqrt{2i})^i$

Also how do I write

$z=1+i$ in polar form and find its roots?

I find these very confusing so step-by-step answers would be a great help, thanks.

Comment: change the "\Sqrt" to "\sqrt". I would do it myself but it is too few changes ;).

Comment: Looking at your question further, and for future reference, please don't place multiple questions into one (even if under the umbrella of complex analysis). i.e the first two are good here, but the  "$z=1+i$ in polar form and find it's roots?" not so much. :)

Comment: Ok, no problem in future I will split them up.

Comment: Assume, $e^{x+jy} = 1-\sqrt{2j}$. $j = e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}}$. Substitute, and calculate the absolute value and argument of RHS. Then equate them to $e^x$ and $y$ respectively.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner that's a little vague, could you post an answer so I have a base for future reference, thanks

Comment: Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

As tpb261 suggested:

$$j = e^{j\pi/2},-1 = e^{j\pi}=e^{-j\pi}$$

$$ 1-\sqrt{2j}=1-2^{1/2}e^{j\pi/4}=1-2^{1/2}\left(\cos(\pi/4)+j \sin(pi/4)\right)$$
$$=1-2^{1/2}\left(2^{-1/2}+j 2^{-1/2}\right)=1-(1+j)=-j= e^{-j\pi/2}$$

Thus

$$\ln(1-\sqrt{2j})=-j\pi/2$$

$$(1-\sqrt{2j})^j=j\exp(\ln((1-\sqrt{2j})))=j\exp(-j\pi/2)=e^{j\pi/2}\exp(-j\pi/2)=1$$

$$\rho e^{j \phi} =z=1+j=2^{1/2}\left(2^{-1/2}+j 2^{-1/2}\right)=2^{1/2}\left(cos(\pi/4)+j\sin(\pi/4)\right)$$
$$=2^{1/2}e^{j\pi/4}$$

Therefore $\rho=2^{1/2}$ and $\phi=\pi/4$.